# JS -> Uncaught ReferenceError: Dolphins is not defined

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to get better at JS as I am very weak in the language so took a course and I'm on one of the challenges.
I'm sure there is probably an easier way to get my answers on this task but that's not what I'm looking for here, I'm getting the error described in the title but not sure why... when I run the script on index.html file I get the error:

***Uncaught ReferenceError: Dolphins is not defined***

Any help I would really appreciate it on what is causing this error :)

```
const teamA = Dolphins;
const teamB = Koalas;

const avgScoreDolphins = 96 + 108 + 89 / 3;
console.log(avgScoreDolphins)

const avgScoreKoalas = 88 + 91 + 110 / 3;
console.log(avgScoreKoalas)

if (avgScoreDolphins >= avgScoreKoalas) {
    console.log(`The winning team is ${teamA}`)
} else if (avgScoreKoalas >= avgScoreDolphins) {
    console.log(`The winning team is ${teamB}`)
}
else (avgScoreDolphins === avgScoreKoalas); {
    console.log(`The competition has ended in a draw with ${teamA} and ${teamB}`)
}
```

```
const teamA = Dolphins;
const teamB = Koalas;

const avgScoreDolphins = 96 + 108 + 89 / 3;
console.log(avgScoreDolphins)

const avgScoreKoalas = 88 + 91 + 110 / 3;
console.log(avgScoreKoalas)

if (avgScoreDolphins >= avgScoreKoalas) {
    console.log(`The winning team is ${teamA}`)
} else if (avgScoreKoalas >= avgScoreDolphins) {
    console.log(`The winning team is ${teamB}`)
}
else (avgScoreDolphins === avgScoreKoalas); {
    console.log(`The competition has ended in a draw with ${teamA} and ${teamB}`)
}
```

Comment: Where  do `Dolphins` and `Koalas` come from ? any other file or what ?

Comment: Where are `Dolphins` and `Koalas` being defined? They are being assigned to `teamA` and `teamB` as if they are a different variable. If you mean to make `teamA` and `teamB` just text, be sure to wrap `Dolphins` and `Koalas` in quotes (").

Comment: You must use double-quote in the variable names, like so: `const teamA = "Dolphins";`

Comment: Oh my god!!!! I'm so stupid!! I've been working on JS exercises and challenges all day...I think I need to walk away.... I feel so stupid!!

Comment: Thank you all for the fast responses!!! I can't believe that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that you haven't defined the variable `Dolphines` yet. So JavaScript thinks, that `Dolphines` is a variable. But it isn't one because it isn't defined anywhere.

Since you probably want to assign a value to the variable teamA, you should wrap `Dolphines` with double quotes (").
Of course, you should also wrap `Koalas` in double quotes.

```
const teamA = "Dolphins";
const teamB = "Koalas";
```